# Yelp get request not working

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, yelp

When i do the same request in Postman everything is fine but when i try it in Alamofire i get an error.
I'm user Alamofire in swift for the request. Here is my code.

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["term": searchTerm as AnyObject, "location": "Washington DC" as AnyObject]
//        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [tokenType!: accessToken!]
        Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer Access_token_************************"])
```

Error text:

```
{
    error =     {
        code = "VALIDATION_ERROR";
        description = "Please specify a location or a latitude and longitude";
    };
```

Comment: Do you need a Content-Type: application/json header too?

Comment: @Scriptable I don't think so, same request worked in Postman. Here is the documentation 
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search